# Express - Nodejs - HTTPS Server

Tags: node.js, express, https

i'm using https server with express in my app, the problem is that express never listens on that port, it works with http but not with https

```
app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
    if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
        res.status(400).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message: "Enter a valid JSON object."
        });
    } else {
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
        res.header('Expires', '-1');
        res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        next();
    }
});
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
require('./config/routes.js')(app);
server = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_LOCATION+"ssl.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_LOCATION+"ssl.cert")
    },app).listen(parseInt(process.env.SOCKET_PORT, 10) || 4000, '0.0.0.0',function(){
        console.log('Express server listening to port '+parseInt(process.env.SOCKET_PORT, 10) || 4000);
    });
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

but if i add

```
port=5455
app.listen(port);
```

express starts listening but on different port
any suggestions?

Comment: I have a few questions. 1. Try to output parseInt(process.env.SOCKET_PORT, 10) 2. On what different port your app is starting listening?

Comment: @VladyslavMoisieienkov 1.SOCKETPORT:8989,2.PORT:3437

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your port with a constant number and test it. Also, try to run my code below (it is based on yours and works for me). Write if it doesn't solve your problem.

```
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require('morgan');

app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// for test
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Work");
})

const server = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl.crt")
},app)
server.listen(8000)
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
console.log('Start');
console.log(server.address().port);
```